# definition of specialization vs degeneration : power series vs polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, tropical-geometry

While reading the literature on toric degeneration problems, I notice that sometimes the degeneration problem is described as following:

Whether there exist a flat family $\pi:\mathcal{F} \to \text{Spec}\mathbb{C}[t]$ such that  generic fiber $\pi^{-1}(t_1)\cong X_1$ (say) and special fiber $\pi^{-1}(0)\cong X_0$.
I am happy with this definition because I think it is geometric because $\text{Spec}\mathbb{C}[t]$ represents the affine line.

However, when people consider specialization of curve $\pi: \mathcal{F}\to \text{Spec}\mathbb{C}[[t]]$, Instead of polynomial ring, power series is used.  Is there any geometric reason behind it?

Comment: This is basically the difference between "affine local" and "locally analytically." Recall that one can use analytic neighborhoods (obtained by taking the spectrum of the completion at a point, and thought of as the analogue of a small disc in complex analytic geometry) to compare isomorphism types of singular points, since two curves with (for example) nodes can easily fail to be isomorphic in any affine neighborhood of the node. In this case, one could easily find familes over $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb C [t]$ with isomorphic special fibers such that there are no affine open subsets...

Comment: ...of the base over which the families are isomorphic. By passing to an analytic neighborhood of the special fiber, this should be fairly easy.